# Delegate vs. Class Reference

Tags: swift, delegates, protocols

If I'm in class A and I want to run a function in class B, I can do it in several ways. In my app I use two different ways and they behave differently, however I'm not sure why.

**The first is through delegation.** I setup a protocol, setup the delegate in the prepareForSegue, and then use it to call back to class A from class B:

```
var delegateToParentVC: mainViewDelegate!
delegateToParentVC.sendAsMsg(txtTask.text!, descPassed: txtDesc.text)
```

**My second method is** that in class I assign class A to a variable. Then I'm able to use it to reference functions in class A.

```
let allocVC = AllocationViewController()
allocVC.sendAsMsg(txtTask.text!, descPassed: txtDesc.text)
```

The second method seems easier in setup (no protocol, no prepareForSegue code). However, it causes glitches more often and I don't understand why.

**For example,** whenever I use the second method to run a function in A which has code that dismisses B, it seems to cause trouble. From what I can tell, anytime I need a specific order of operations, I get trouble unless I use delegation.

I'm not posting for a resolution to the glitches. I just really need someone to explain why they are different and give examples of when to use each.

Comment: You're being a bit vague about the "glitches". Since there are a multitude of possible glitches and you're trying to learn, it'd be a good idea to specify said glitches so they can be explained to you. This will help you solidify what you learn from answers provided here.

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi Hi Joshua, I'd actually love to try to solve the glitches on my own after coming to better understand the differences. Delegation seems incredibly unnecessary to me, unless its for type-safe sort of reasons. Why bother with more setup code? So I'm really just trying to understand the differences in how they execute/run and what the best examples would be for when to use each.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem not to understand about classes and instances (object-oriented programming). One class can have many instances; those instances are not the same objects as one another. You do not send messages to view controller *classes* but to view controller *instances*. In your scenario, one view controller *instance* is trying to send a message back to another, already existing view controller *instance*.

Thus, this approach is never going to work at all:

```
let allocVC = AllocationViewController()
allocVC.sendAsMsg(txtTask.text!, descPassed: txtDesc.text)
```

In this approach, you are creating a *completely new* AllocationViewController instance and sending it a message. But that is pointless, because *this* AllocationViewController instance is not *the existing* AllocationViewController instance. It is that *existing* AllocationViewController instance that you want to send a message to.

That is why the *first* approach *does* work. You are setting `delegateToParentVC` to the *actual, existing* AllocationViewController instance.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add an additional point to [@matt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34780366/1664443)'s answer. You are correct that you can call a method by getting ahold of an instance of a class. As we saw with [@matt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34780366/1664443)'s answer, you're creating a new instance of your class which is rarely helpful in this scenario. The better way to do this is to get your existing class instance by accessing your global `sharedApplication` and then finding your class instance from that.

You'll wind up with something like this:

```
let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let vc = app.window?.rootViewController as! AllocationViewController
vc.sendAsMsg(txtTask.text!, descPassed: txtDesc.text)
```

Your final code may be a bit different than mine depending on where `AllocationViewController` is listed in your application hierarchy.